# All AI-algebras are AT-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

It is known that every AI-algebra (i.e. inductive limit of interval algebras) is an AT-algebra (i.e. inductive limit of circle algebras)?

This seems a little bit odd because a building block of an AT-algebra can be embedded in a building block of an AI-algebra. Is there any example to clarify this?

Comment: The way you phrase this question makes it seem like a (non-trivial!) exercise. If this is a known result then presumably you are able to look up the papers in which this is proved. On the other hand, if this is an open question then I think you should give more details about which cases you already know how to do, where you have tried looking, and so on.

Comment: It is a well-known result. Its proof is on page 57 of "Classification of Nuclear $C^{\ast}$-Algebras, Entropy in Operator Algebras, M. Rordam, E. Stormer". 

I am looking for an intuitive description or possibly an example. As I mentioned before, its converse makes more sense to me.

Comment: The way you phrase it is wrong. When you assume that the C*-algebras in question are unital and simple, then I guess that it is true.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what you said, the building block of an AI-algebra, namely $C([0,1],M_n)$, can naturally be embedded into the building block of an AT-algebra, namely $C(\mathbb{T},M_n)$, and not conversely.

Indeed let $\pi\colon\mathbb{T}\to[0,1]$ be a surjective, continuous map (e.g., identifying the north and south halfcircles). Then the map
$$
C([0,1],M_n)\to C(\mathbb{T},M_n),\quad f\mapsto f\circ\pi
$$
is an injective ${}^*$-homomorphism.

Comment: But there are also continuous surjections from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb T$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But the homomorphism $C([0,1],M_n)\to C(\mathbb{T},M_n)$ feels to me 'more natural' than the map $C(\mathbb{T},M_n)\to C([0,1],M_n)$. For instance, the latter 'forgets' K-theory.